# Update NaN values with dictionary of values nased on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have data frame like this:

```
   c1  c2
0   a  12  
1   b  NaN
2   a  45
3   c  NaN
4   c  32
5   b  NaN
```

and I have dictionary like this

```
di = {
'a': 10, 'b': 20, 'c':30
}
```

I want to update my data frame like this

```
   c1  c2
0   a  12  
1   b  20
2   a  45
3   c  30
4   c  32
5   b  20
```

is there any way to do it without using long lambda function with conditions
**Here's the code to create your data frame**

```
a = pd.DataFrame({
    'c1': ['a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'b'],
    'c2': [12, np.NaN, 45, np.NaN, 32, np.NaN]
})
di = {
    'a': 10, 'b': 20, 'c':30
}
di
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) for replace only missing values:

```
a['c2'] = a['c2'].fillna(a['c1'].map(di))
print (a)
  c1    c2
0  a  12.0
1  b  20.0
2  a  45.0
3  c  30.0
4  c  32.0
5  b  20.0
```

Last if all values of `c1` are in keys of dictionary, all values of missing values are replaced and is possible convert to integers:

```
a['c2'] = a['c2'].fillna(a['c1'].map(di)).astype(int)
print (a)
  c1  c2
0  a  12
1  b  20
2  a  45
3  c  30
4  c  32
5  b  20
```

Comment: I am surprised you did not flag my question this time for duplicate !! Thanx for the answer it works !!

Comment: Why apologise for doing your duty to the community? @Manan if a question has been asked before, it's always better to point them to established resources than repeat knowledge again.

Comment: @Manan - You can check my profile, there is a lot of very often pandas dupes, this is my main sorce for closing dupes. You can check it, maybe help in future.

Comment: I saw your profile befor too.. and I am kinda new to stack so i dont know better ways to navigate there... so I post new question!

Answer (score 1):

You can use apply() method to deal with this.
Create a function and then apply that function to the required features.

```
`def deal_na(cols):
    x=cols[0]
    y=cols[1]
    if pd.isnull(y):
        return di[x]
    else:
        return y
 a['c2'] = a[['c1','c2']].apply(deal_na,axis=1)`
```

Here, we pass values of feature 'c1' and 'c2' as a list to the function in the cols variable. Then we assign each value to 2 variables x and y. We check whether y is null or not. If it is null then replace with di[x] otherwise return as it is.